# Find all transforms for an array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get all the transforms of my Enemy Cannon's, so I declared the `enemyCans` variable as follows:

```
GameObject[] enemyCans;
```

Then, I assigned the following value to it in the `start()` method:

```
enemyCans = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("EnemyCannon").transform;
```

However, I cannot use `.transform` here like I could when I assigned my player's transform value like so:

```
player= GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
```

I know this likely has to do with `enemyCans` being an array, but I'm not sure how else to get those transform values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that `enemyCans` is an array of game-objects (`GameObject[]`).

If you want the transforms, you will then have to iterate through the `enemyCans` array and retrieve each of their transforms individually.

I hope that helps!

**EDIT:**
Full credit to @Orphid's answer below for suggesting this.
For OP's clarification, you would need to use Linq (`namespace System.Linq`) for this. Also add `ToArray()` at the end to convert it into an array.

Example:

```
Transform[] enemyXforms = 
GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("EnemyCannon").Select(cannon => cannon.transform).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is to do with the type being an array, something like

```
foreach(var cannon in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("EnemyCannon"))
{
  //aggregate result here
}
```

If it's just an array, you could also select the transforms like this:

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("EnemyCannon").Select(cannon => cannon.transform);
```